# Chain complex and free resolution

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

If $I \subset R = k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is an ideal. Then why:
$0 \to C_i \to \dots\to C_0 \to R \to R/I \to0$
is a free resolution of $R/I $
if and only if
$0 \to C_i \to \dots\to C_0 \to I \to 0$ is a free resolution of $I$?

The extra term in the first sequence $R$ is not necessary? Can someone show me a proof? My old experience tells me I just need isomorphism for chains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sequences are exact (assuming they are exact anyway at the $C_i$'s) if and only if $\operatorname{Image}(C_0 \to R) = I$.

Comment: Or to say $I = Ker(R \to R/I)$, is this not just the fundamental theorem?

Comment: This is what certainly holds. By the definition of exactness, the statement of my answer then follows.

Comment: Sorry, but I meant how do you justify $Im(C_0 \to R) = I$? That's not included in the definition of exactness? I wrote $I = Ker$ because I used the fundamental theorem of homomorphism.

Comment: In the first sequence, exactness tells you $Im(C_0 \to R)=Ker(R \to R/I)=I$, so thats definitely definition of exactness...In the second sequence, exactness tells you, that $C_0 \to I$ is surjective, which is the same as saying $Im(C_0 \to R)=I$.

Comment: Right, each map is a homomorphsm. Right, by the fundamental theorem, $Ker = I$, and the equality passes to $Ker = Im$ by the definition of exactness. And the second sequence is a repetition. Right.

Comment: Just one tiny thing. I thought that surjectivity is only for short exact sequences, not general exactness. My complex has more than 3 objects.

Comment: Whenever we have a zero-map in an exact sequence, the previous map is surjective (and the next map is injective). This follows immediatley from the definition of exactness and holds for any exact sequence regardless of the length,

Comment: Right,this is because the condition is set by the tails of the chain. Right, right...another trivial question, but why doesn't one need to show each object in the chain are free (oh wait, that is the assumption?)?

Comment: Of course, this is the assumption. If you assume one of the sequences to be a free resolution, then the $C_i$'s are automatically assumed to be free.

Comment: Right..right by assuming each $C_i$ as I thought, this also includes everything in the chain, $R, I, R/I, 0$. Engish isn't my 1st language, so I often get mixed up with all these words.

Comment: Um, sorry to bring this up again, but you mentioned in an earlier comment that the subjectivity $C_o \to I$ is the same as saying $Im(C_0 \to R) = I$, but you really mean $Im(C_0 \to I) = I = Ker(R \to R/I) = Im(C_0 \to R)$ right?